# Spring Application runs via Intellij's Run, but doesn't via mvn spring-boot:run

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

**Problem**

I’m working on a Java Spring Application. I'm able to run this application via Run command of Intellij and it works without any problems. However, even if it starts with `mvn spring-boot:run` command, it fails during runtime with `unnamed module`error. The provided dependency can not initiated its classes.

The projects Java version is 11.

**SOLVED**
Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/10870817/sot
JDK setting in Intellij was different from JDK in JAVA_HOME. It worked after fixing JAVA_HOME.

**Error**

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; 
nested exception is java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider: Provider com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl could not be instantiated] with root cause 
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class 
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module
```

**Details:**

This application depends on a package which is provided by an external party as jar file together with its dependencies:

```
└── lib
    ├── ProvidedDependency.jar
    ├── ItsDependency1.jar
    └── ItsDependency2.jar
```

I installed externally provided packages to my local maven repository:

```bash
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=lib/ProvidedDependency.jar -DgroupId=com.external -DartifactId=provided-dep -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=lib/ItsDependency1.jar -DgroupId=com.external1 -DartifactId=first-dep -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=lib/ItsDependency2.jar -DgroupId=com.external2 -DartifactId=second-dep -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

I added these dependencies to my pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.external</groupId>
  <artifactId>provided-dep</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</depedency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.external1</groupId>
  <artifactId>first-dep</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</depedency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.external2</groupId>
  <artifactId>second-dep</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</depedency>
```

Moreover, I already added my local repository into pom.xml as well:

```xml
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>local-repo</id>
    <url>file://{user.home}/.m2/repository
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Morever, org.spring.framework.boot is added as parent to pom.xml, too:

```xml
<parent>
  <groupId>org.spring.framework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

**Summary**

Since Spring Application runs via Intellij's Run, but I need to run it via command line, so that it can be containerized.

What could be root cause, is there anything I'm missing during execution or building the project?

Comment: is that all you get as error message?

Comment: error message is quite long: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider: Provider com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl could not be instantiated] with root cause


java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module

Comment: The error should go in the post, not a comment.

Comment: sure, I put the error message in the post. I didn't do it, because I assumed the error is specific with mvn spring-boot:run since it's running via Intellij:Run perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite sure that your JDK setting in Intellij is different from JDK in JAVA_HOME. Make sure both are the same

Comment: You're right. Such a simple error caused me hours. I'm putting your answer in the post. Thanks !